# xslt xpath muenchian grouping

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <rss>
     <channel>
      <item>
       <status>Identify</status>
       <component>Department A</component>
       <component>Department ABC</component>
      </item>
      <item>
       <status>Identify</status>
       <component>Department B</component>
       <component>Department BCD</component>
      </item>
      <item>
       <status>In Progress</status>
       <component>Department A</component>
       <component>Redundant</component>
      </item>
      <item>
       <status>Identify</status>
       <component>Department B</component>
       <component>Redundant</component>
      </item>
     </channel>
    </rss>
```

---

I want the output in html to look like the following table

```
Departments       | Identify | In Progress
Department A      |    0     |    1
Department B      |    1     |    0
Department ABC    |    1     |    0
Department BCD    |    1     |    0
Total (4 records) |    3     |    1
```

---

This is the logic behind the numbers.
If an item has multiple components, choose only one component with the longest name.
Any component that doesn't start with 'Department' has to be ignored.
There is always only one status per item.

I am very new to xslt and xpath. I have been stuck at this for multiple days now even after a lot of googling. Any guru out there, please help :)
Really appreciate.

Thanks a lot.
Pyi Pai

---

This is what I have tried so far... Obviously, it is still a long way out from where I want to be. But I am clueless for next steps since xslt logic is so much different from normal sequential programming logic.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:key name="components" match="/rss/channel/item/component" use="./text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/rss/channel">
        <xsl:for-each select="item/component[generate-id(.) = generate-    id(key('components', .))]">
            <xsl:sort select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="contains(text(),'Department')">
            <h1>
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(key('components', .))"/>
            </h1>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you use XSLT 1.0 only? If you have an XSLT 2.0 processor, Muenchian grouping is not needed to group elements.

Comment: Ya, unfortunately, I can only use XSLT 1.0 only.

Comment: Fine. I am not sure whether grouping is required here. Can there be more than one "identify" or "in progress" for a given department?

Comment: yes there can be Mathias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not really need to use Muenchian grouping for this. The solution below works without any grouping mechanism.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/rss/channel">
        <html>
            <body>
            <table border="solid">
                <tr>
                    <td>Departments</td>
                    <td>Identify</td>
                    <td>In Progress</td>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//component"/>
                <tr>
                <xsl:variable name="total" select="count(//component[starts-with(.,'Department') and not(. = preceding::component/text())])"/>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Total (',$total,' records)')"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(//item[status = 'Identify'])"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(//item[status = 'In Progress'])"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="component[starts-with(.,'Department') and not(. = preceding::component/text())]">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(//item[status = 'Identify' and component = current() and not(component[. != current() and string-length(.) &gt; string-length(current())])])"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(//item[status = 'In Progress' and component = current() and not(component[. != current() and string-length(.) &gt; string-length(current())])])"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="solid">
         <tr>
            <td>Departments</td>
            <td>Identify</td>
            <td>In Progress</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Department A</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Department ABC</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Department B</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Department BCD</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Total (4 records)</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>1</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Rendered HTML Output**

> [image]

Comment: although it would be perfect if you can incorporate this as well. "If an item has multiple components, choose only one component with the longest name."

Comment: @user3304762 You're right - I overlooked this. I have edited my answer - it's slightly more complicated now.

Comment: omg! that was quick! thanks a lot @Mathias. now I wonder why I wasted days sitting on this. should have posted here for guru's help sooner :-) many thanks again.